# jax.experimental importing error Python 3.9

Tags: python, importerror, jax

I'd seen previous errors importing form JAX from several years ago (https://github.com/google/jax/issues/372), but the post implied an update would fix it. I just installed JAX and am trying to get set up on a jupyter notebook. Could you let me know what might be going wrong?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 4>()
      1 ########## JAX ON MNIST #####################
      2 # Import some additional JAX and dataloader helpers
      3 from jax.scipy.special import logsumexp
----> 4 from jax.experimental import optimizers
      6 import torch
      7 from torchvision import datasets, transforms

ImportError: cannot import name 'optimizers' from 'jax.experimental' (/Users/XXX/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/experimental/__init__.py)
```

I saw that the similar previous error was in 2019 and implied a version difference would fix it. I did not know where to go from there.

Comment: Issues page might be where you can get help resolving this.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CHANGELOG](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#jax-0-3-16)

> #### jax 0.3.16
>
> - Deprecations:
>
>   - Removed `jax.experimental.optimizers`; it has long been a deprecated alias of `jax.example_libraries.optimizers`.

So it sounds like if you're using JAX version 0.3.16 or newer, you should do

```py
from jax.example_libraries import optimizers
```

But as noted in the [`jax.example_libraries.optimizers`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.example_libraries.optimizers.html#module-jax.example_libraries.optimizers) documentation, this is not well-supported code and you'll probably have a better experience with something like [Optax](https://github.com/deepmind/optax) or [JAXopt](https://github.com/google/jaxopt).

Comment: This worked for all the missing experimental subfunctions. Thank you. (I couldn't upvote)